# como creo paginacion en una entrada en wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, entrada

Quisiera hacer una paginacion en la entrada de wordpress

busque por la web intentando con <--nextpage--> en el editor y agregando la función  en el archivo sinple.php pero no me funciona

Conocen algun plugin en el que pueda paginar solo entradas o artículos que sean largos , por ejemplo que tengan mas de 6 párrafos se pagina el contenido o por cantida de caracteres o algo así

Le agradezco sus respuestas

Comment: Necesitas recortar los textos y que con un botón puedas ver el texto siguiente de la entrada ?

Comment: Necesito dividir el articulo en varias partes , si asi es ...

Answer (score 0):

Te doy opciones para que puedas hacerlo :

1) La más sencilla :

Usar Read More en el post :

```
        <?php the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser ); ?>
```

Aquí tienes una guía completa : https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

2) Un poco más complicada :

**Esta la use hace mucho tiempo para partir un post en dos columnas, es decir un Flipbook.**

```
        <div id="mybook" class="flipbook-container ">               
            <div class="page-container  page-left">
                <div  class="page-content">
                <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="contenido texto">
                        <?php $content = split_content();?>
                        <?php echo '<span>', array_shift($content), '</span>'; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="bgr-space-3" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bgr-space-2.png" alt="#"/>
            </div>
            <div class="page-container page-right">
                <div class="page-content">
                    <div class="contenido texto">
                        <?php echo '<span>', implode($content), '</span>'; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="bgr-space-3" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bgr-space-2.png" alt="#"/>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>  <?php endif; wp_reset_query();?>
            <div class="page-container contra-portada">
                <img class="bgr-space-3" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bgr-space-2.png" alt="#"/>
            </div>                  
        </div>
```

Debes agregar la siguiente función al functions.php de WP :

```
  // Función para mostrar contenido en 2 columnas
  function split_content() {
      global $more;
      $more = true;
      $content = preg_split('/<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>/i',get_the_content('more'));
      for($c = 0, $csize = count($content); $c < $csize; $c++) {
         $content[$c] = apply_filters('the_content', $content[$c]);
  }
  return $content;
}
```